# I am having an error that says "ModelForm has no model class specified."

Tags: django, python-3.x

I was just watching a tutorial in youtube and i was just following what was indicated buti still got those errors.

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 50)

    class Meta:
        model : User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm

def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render (request, 'users/register.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I think the syntax is wrong, `model = User` is correct. Check out [modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Comment: Thank you so much, Ive been stuck for more than a day thinking that i had the exact same syntax. Thanks a lot!